# using if/else in do/while in c#

Tags: c#

```
namespace himiC_sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WELCOME TO THE SHOPPING CART!\nFollowing options are available to you:\n1. Add an item to cart\n2. Remove an item from the cart\n3. View the cart\n4. Checkout and Pay\n5. Exit");
                Console.WriteLine("please inter your chice");
                x = Console.Read();
                if (x == '1')
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Available items are:\n1.shirt\n2.pant\n3.shoes\n4.fish\n5.oil");
                Console.WriteLine("please inter the items name:");
                string j = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            } while (x != '5');
        }
   } 
}
```

but the program dont take input when i  expected to take input like----

[image]

but it repeats my console.writeline() method in state of takeing input

Comment: Do not use Console.Read but Console.ReadLine

Comment: @Rahul Apparently, `char`s and `int`s are automatically converted to each other when necessary (according to my experiments just now).

Comment: @Rahul char is implicitly coverted to int in C#, but the opposite is not true. `int x = Console.Read();` and `int y = 'a';` compiles .

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails because [Console.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reads just the next character from the input stream.
I suppose that you press 1 followed by the enter. The char 1 is read by the `Console.Read` but the newline is still in the buffer.
When your code reaches the `Console.Readline` where the user is supposed to enter the item, the ReadLine finds the newline still in the input buffer and exits immediately.

Just change your Console.Read to a Console.ReadLine, of course changing the type of the variable that receives the input

```
string menuChoice;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("WELCOME TO THE SHOPPING CART!\nFollowing options are available to you:\n1. Add an item to cart\n2. Remove an item from the cart\n3. View the cart\n4. Checkout and Pay\n5. Exit");
    Console.WriteLine("please inter your chice");
    menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    if (menuChoice == "1")
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Available items are:\n1.shirt\n2.pant\n3.shoes\n4.fish\n5.oil");
      Console.WriteLine("please inter the items name:");
      string j = Console.ReadLine();
    }
} while (menuChoice != "5");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the input from ReadLine to int:

```
        int choice;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WELCOME TO THE SHOPPING CART!\nFollowing options are available to you:\n1. Add an item to cart\n2. Remove an item from the cart\n3. View the cart\n4. Checkout and Pay\n5. Exit");
            Console.WriteLine("please inter your chice");
            choice = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Available items are:\n1.shirt\n2.pant\n3.shoes\n4.fish\n5.oil");
                Console.WriteLine("please inter the items name:");
                string j = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } while (choice != 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ReadLine() instead and convert the input into an int for comparison inside the `if()`

`x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`